# Can't compile program that uses SDL after upgrade to 11.10 - undefined reference to SDL_Init

Tags: 11.10, gcc, sdl

I've just upgraded from 11.4 to 11.10 and at least one thing seems to be broken: I have a C++ program that is using SDL and OpenGL. I was able to compile and run it just fine before the upgrade. Now I get linker errors, for example

```
undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
```

I have `libsdl1.2debian` and `libsdl1.2-dev` packages installed, I believe that is all I need (but I might be wrong). I compile the program like this:

`gcc -I /usr/include/SDL -lSDL -o test test.cpp`

Any idea what can be causing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, solved. Apparently, for some mysterious reason, the order of the gcc options now matters. So when I do:

```
gcc -I /usr/include/SDL -o test test.cpp -lSDL
```

(moved the `-lSDL` option to the end) everthing works just fine. I'd love to know why it suddenly matters, when before if did not, but for now I'm happy that stuff works again.

Comment: Maybe you should check the release notes for the version of `gcc` in 11.10.

Comment: Thanks, very helpfull. You can also completly turn around the order to gcc -o test test.cpp -I /usr/include/SDL -lSDL which is useful when you use pkg-config as you can then still get the cflags and libs in one go like  gcc -o test test.cpp \`pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl\`

Comment: Read about why here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417169/why-does-the-library-linker-flag-sometimes-have-to-go-at-the-end-using-gcc

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse: I've same problem, but I resolve.

- Select project
- Project>Properties
- C/C++ Build>Settings - Tool Settings>GCC C Compiler - Include paths (-l)>"/usr/include/SDL"
- C/C++ Build>Settings - Tool Settings>GCC C Linker - Libraries (-l)>"SDL"
- Apply

...then build project and run...

Answer (score 1):

A simple GNU `Makefile` for a project which uses SDL:

```
CXXFLAGS:=(shell pkg-config --cflags sdl2) $(CXXFLAGS)
LDLIBS:=$(shell pkg-config --libs sdl2) $(LDLIBS)

all: test
```

Where a file `test.cpp` exists in the same directory as the `Makefile`.

(Note that I've used `sdl2` instead of `sdl`, since SDL 1.2 is basically dead now.)

GNU `make` will magically figure out the command for calling `g++`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using G++ and it didn't work, and switching to GCC it works.  I am writing in C though.

Using Code::Blocks, the library flag is `-lSDL2`